# How to sort an alphanumeric array just based on number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sorting, arraylist

consider the following array:

```
['state1035', 'dm5', 'state123', 'county247', 'county2']
```

sorting this array on basis of number output should be:

```
['county2' ,'dm5', 'state123', 'county247', 'state1035']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the strings will have numbers together and at the end you can use match to extract the number and sort it:

```js
let arr = ['state1035', 'dm5', 'state123', 'county247', 'county2'];
console.log(arr.sort((a,b) => a.match(/\d+$/).pop() - b.match(/\d+$/).pop()));
```

The match method used within the compare function will return the array of matched sub-strings from the given string. The regex `\d+` will match with numbers at the end and we are sorting based on these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) against only the numbers in the string, and then [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the strings based on those numbers.

```js
const data = ['state1035', 'dm5', 'bob0Bob', 'state123', 'county247', 'county2'];

const regex = /\d+/;

const result = data.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.match(regex) - b.match(regex);
});

console.log(result);
```